# Emergency Call Madagascar Satellite Phone

Tags: emergencies, satellite-phones

I will go to rural areas in Madagascar and have an Inmarsat satellite phone. Does anyone know which number I can dial with this phone in an emergency?

I already know that 117 is the local emergency number, but it only works with "normal" cell phones.

Any help would be very much appreciated.